# Detecting html5 audio support with Modernizr

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr

Is it possible to detect if the browser has Html5 Audio support through Modernizr? If so how is this done? If not are there any work around's? There's few resources on Google explaining this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I was about to post a third "read the docs" answer but the other two were posted seconds before. The documentation should be your first resource, not Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, through modernizr.audio. It supports a number of audio formats (currently ogg, mp3, m4a & wmv). Example:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = Modernizr.audio.ogg ? 'background.ogg' :
            Modernizr.audio.mp3 ? 'background.mp3' :
                                  'background.m4a';
audio.play();
```

More info in the [documentation](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#audio).

Comment: Yeah I tried this:<script type="text/javascript">
 if (Modernizr.audio){
   <?php include("music.php"); ?>
} else {
   <?php include("error.php"); ?>
}
</script> and it doesn't seem to work.. I'll give that a shot, thanks man

Comment: how do I execute stuff inside the if statement?

Comment: The audio doesn't even play and http://i55.tinypic.com/2qdbl3k.png in this image, I shouldn't be having the "} else { error}" tagged on to the end.

Comment: @Michael please post the full, generated HTML on a paste site (like gist.github.com)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Modernizr detects audio support, according to [the documentation](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/##audio) (that's a link), which even includes a code sample (copied below):

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = Modernizr.audio.ogg ? 'background.ogg' :
            Modernizr.audio.mp3 ? 'background.mp3' :
                                  'background.m4a';
audio.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this code and it worked fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
<title>Play Audio</title>
<script src="script/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script/modernizr-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentFile = "";
function playAudio() {

    var oAudio = document.getElementById('myaudio');
    // See if we already loaded this audio file.
    if ($("#audiofile").val() !== currentFile) {
        oAudio.src = $("#audiofile").val();
        currentFile = $("#audiofile").val();
    }
        var test = $("#myaudio");
        test.src = $("#audiofile").val();
    oAudio.play();   
}

$(function() {
    if (Modernizr.audio) {
        if (Modernizr.audio.wav) {
            $("#audiofile").val("sounds/sample.wav"); 
        }
        if (Modernizr.audio.mp3) {
            $("#audiofile").val("sounds/sample.mp3");
        }
    }
    else {
      $("#HTML5Audio").hide();
      $("#OldSound").html('<embed src="sounds/sample.wav" autostart=false width=1 height=1 id="LegacySound" enablejavascript="true" >');
    }

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="text-align: center;"> 
 <h1>Click to Play Sound<br /></h1>
<div id="HTML5Audio">
<input id="audiofile" type="text" value="" style="display: none;"/><br />

<button id="play" onclick="playAudio();">
    Play
</button>
</div>
<audio id="myaudio">
    <script>
    function LegacyPlaySound(soundobj) {
      var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
      thissound.Play();
    }
    </script>
    <span id="OldSound"></span>        
    <input type="button" value="Play Sound" onClick="LegacyPlaySound('LegacySound')">
</audio>
```

Just add the audio with the right name in the folder and add the modernizer files with the Jquery stuff and you're done.

Comment: Attribution: http://www.misfitgeek.com/2011/08/play-sound-in-html5-and-cross-browser-support-with-backward-compatability/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#installing Half way down.