# Changing <source> with HTML5 Audio works in Chrome but not Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, html5-audio

I'm trying to make an HTML5 audio playlist that will work in each major browser: Chrome,Safari, Firefox, IE9+. However, I can't figure out how to change the sources in a cross browser compatible way.

**UPDATED** For example, changing the `<source>` tag's `src`s works in Chrome but not Safari. While @eivers88's solution below using `canPlayType` works it seems easier to me just to change the `<source>` tag's `src`s. Can anyone explain to me why my code directly below works in Chrome but not Safari?

JS:

```
var audioPlayer=document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
var mp4Source=$('source#mp4');
var oggSource=$('source#ogg');
$('button').click(function(){    
  audioPlayer.pause();
  mp4Source.attr('src', 'newFile.mp4');
  oggSource.attr('src', 'newFile.ogg');
  audioPlayer.load();
  audioPlayer.play();
});
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button">Next song</button>
<audio id="audioPlayer">
  <source id="mp4" src="firstFile.mp4" type="audio/mp4"/> 
  <source id="ogg" src="firstFile.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />                      
</audio>
```

Inspecting the HTML after the button click, the `<source src=""/>` does change in Safari, its just that the HTTP request is not made, so they the files don't get `load()`ed and `play()`ed. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working [exapmle](http://aaroneivers.com/html5/audio.html). It's a little bit different from what you have but hopefully this can be helpful.

HTML:

```
<button type="button">Next song</button>
```

Javascript/jquery:

```
    var songs = [
    '1976', 'Ballad of Gloria Featherbottom', 'Black Powder' 
]
var track = 0;
var audioType = '.mp3'
var audioPlayer = document.createElement('audio');

$(window).load(function() {

    if(!!audioPlayer.canPlayType('audio/ogg') === true){
        audioType = '.ogg' //For firefox and others who do not support .mp3
    }

    audioPlayer.setAttribute('src', 'music/' + songs[track] + audioType);
    audioPlayer.setAttribute('controls', 'controls');
    audioPlayer.setAttribute('id', 'audioPlayer');
    $('body').append(audioPlayer);
    audioPlayer.load();
    audioPlayer.play();

});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    audioPlayer.pause();
    if(track < songs.length - 1){
        track++;
        audioPlayer.setAttribute('src', 'music/' + songs[track] + audioType);
        audioPlayer.load();
        audioPlayer.play();
    }
    else {
        track = 0;
        audioPlayer.setAttribute('src', 'music/' + songs[track] + audioType);
        audioPlayer.load();
        audioPlayer.play();
    }
})
```

Comment: Also, if you're on pc, make sure you have quick time player installed! A mistake I have made before! =D

Comment: -@eivers, thanks but this will fail on Firefox b/c there is no `ogg` mime-type. That is why I'm using the `<source>` tag and not just the `audioPlayer`'s src attribute. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: That's why I added the `if(!!audioPlayer.canPlayType('audio/mp3') === true)` statement, if it is false you can add an `else { audioType = '.ogg' }` and then change the audioType variable to .ogg

Comment: Or you could even just have `if(!!audioPlayer.canPlayType('audio/ogg') === true){ audioType = '.ogg' }` so there is no need for an else statement

Comment: I'm still confused on why Safari can't use the `<source>` tags (Chrome can), but it does look like this is the problem and just changing the `src` attribute on the `<audio>` tag works as expected.

Comment: -@eivers, your solution (the link you provided) doesn't work on Firefox. Do you have the .ogg audio files for that? I'm wondering if the `canPlayType` is even working?

Comment: @timpeterson - Sorry about that, I should have just made it cross browser compliant in the first place, it should work now though.

Comment: -@eivers, thanks I'm trying to replicate your code on my localhost. The only problem is b/c I created the audio element with javascript, it doesn't know what the content header is and so it thinks the mime-type="text/html". Here's the error message: `"HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost/uploads/9/v1/Miaow-02-Hidden.ogg failed."` Thoughts?

Comment: @timpeterson I'm somewhat confused, are you wrapping your js in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`?

Comment: yep this is weird, i'm using apache server and same issue whether or not I make any mime-type declarations in my .htaccess

Comment: Ohh yeah that's a whole other issue on its own, my script should work though once you get your mimeTypes properly set, good luck!

Comment: They are properly set to my knowledge, can i ask your server config?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12969/discussion-between-eivers88-and-tim-peterson)

Comment: oh man! i had simply just misspelled the name of the folder serving these files. Ugh!!! problem solved. It now plays in safari, chrome, firefox. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Example link has broken, can you give me another working example?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, Safari can't use the `<source>` tags for swapping between songs but Chrome can. Just changing what gets loaded into the `src` attribute on the `<audio>` tag works on both Chrome and Safari but then there is the ogg vs. mp3 issue.

I guess one way to get around this ogg vs. mp3 issue is to use Modernizr does feature detection to load the ogg mime-type in Firefox and the mp3 in Chrome/Safari. Here's a reference on that:
[Detecting html5 audio support with Modernizr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867807/detecting-html5-audio-support-with-modernizr).

Answer (score 1):

**Just a quick addition to the topic (in 2023):**

I had a similar problem. The code was working in Safari, but not Chrome.
I had Javascript code that swapped the `src` of the `<source>` element. That worked fine in Safari, but Chrome refused to recognize the file and showed a disabled player state. What I was missing, and what I learned here, is that you need to call `load()` as well.

So adding this fixed it for me.

```js
audioPlayer.load();
```

*Safari seems to auto-detect the source change, Chrome did not.*