# How to check if new Audio is supported by browser?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audioformat

In safari 5, new Audio is not supported, so the error console displays :

```
TypeError : 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Audio')
```

How could I programatically know whether new Audio is supported by browser ?

Comment: `if ('Audio' in window)`

Comment: You can use canPlayType() method. You can look this link
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_canplaytype.asp

Comment: Thank very much for all. Your codes work perfectly !!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you might just try it...

```
var createAudio = function() {
 try {
    return new Audio(); 
 } catch(e) {
    return false;
 }
};
var audio = createAudio();
if(audio) {
  // start playing... or check formats etc.
}
```

In case there is exception, the Audio class does not exist and returns false.

For more detailed solution check Modernzr library: http://modernizr.com/docs/#audio

The related solution is here [Detecting html5 audio support with Modernizr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867807/detecting-html5-audio-support-with-modernizr)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions to check if it exists.

Check that the type of `Audio` isn't "undefined".

```
if (typeof window.Audio !== "undefined")
```

Check if `window` has a property `Audio`.

```
if ("Audio" in window)
```

The below *could* generate an error.

```
if (window.Audio)
```

But, this code doesn't guarantee that it's a good Audio implementation. It could just be some random script doing this: `window.Audio = 'http://link.to/some/mp3'`.